# Unsure which function would work in Excel (IF-THEN, VLOOKUP, etc)

Tags: excel

I am coding something for a yearly tournament I do.  Scores need to be listed in 2 spots on the form, but I don't want to have to manually enter them in both spots to avoid mistakes.

```
Buffalo     1   Detroit     2
Carolina    4   Los Angeles 6
Chicago     2   Nashville   0
Colorado    3   New York    1
```

Is there a way to code another cell to find the value of "Buffalo" (for example) in either column A or C and return the value directly to the right (in column B or D).  Because values listed above may switch around when I do the game schedule, I need the 2nd set of scores to be "smart" in that they can find "Buffalo" in either of those columns and give me the correct value.

I've been doing some trial and error using different functions and haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Thanks in advance for your help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qoVT.jpg)

Comment: I may misuderstood the desired output, do you have a different place than these 4 columns, where you have the list where you want the output?

Comment: Yes, in a separate cell, I wanted to search columns A and C for "Buffalo" and have it return the value directly to the right of that cell when it finds it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use SUMIF()

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$C$4,G2,$B$1:$D$4)
```

Note the same size but offset ranges.

[image]

Comment: Ok, that works when I set up one that's simple like what I outlined, but the value in the cell I want to match it to is actually the result of a formula =INDEX(AM2:AM9,MATCH(1,AL2:AL9,0))  That formula in my actual workbook would give the value of Buffalo, but when I plug that cell into the sumif function, I get 0

Comment: not sure I understand what that formula has to do with this example.

Comment: so you get `Buffalo` with that formula and you want to combine the two?

Comment: How can I attach a sample like what you did in yours where it looks like the actual spreadsheet?

Comment: I do not know how your actual spread sheet looks.  so I have no idea how to make it work for your specific use.  I can only go off what you provide.

Comment: I know, how can I attach a sample so you can see what the whole thing actually looks like?

Comment: post your screen capture on imgur.com and link to it in your original post.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/cdQY8  That's the image.  I have it standing on E7, which is what I want it to match.  Where the 0 is in cell M7 is where I want this formula to go.  I want it to search o20:u23 and x20:ae23

Comment: Won't work, the two lists are 9 columns apart and the numbers are 10.  The ranges must be the same size.  Sorry.

Comment: If you move the second set of numbers to Column AD then: `=SUMIF($O30:$X$33,E7,$U30:$AD$33)`  This requires the names be in columns O and X and the numbers in Columns U and AD.

Comment: Ahhh, ok.  I'll actually move column X to column Y to keep my spacing the way I want it.  I'll make sure it functions right and then I'll green check your response.  Thanks for your patience and help!